# animate vector element to swing like a pendulum with SVG or Canvas?

Tags: animation, canvas, svg

I have a image which i would like to animate on my web page.

Currently i am using a gif.

http://dev.thepenline.com/TEMP/Hol_10_swingingBell.gif

I would like to have more control on its animation, which js lib/framework would be best to help me out?

Should i use canvas or SVG?
Which (small) library is best to use?

I happen to know a little [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/)
But i am not sure how to get this effect done.

Comment: what kinda control you're expecting ?

Comment: @Ninja smoother animation and vector based. (scalable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done something with SVG that's close to what you're trying to achieve: http://live.echo-flow.com/stackoverflow/clock.svg

In case I ever take the example down, here's the relevant code.

clock.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

<rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" fill="none" stroke="blue" id="border"/>

<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="clock.js"></script>

</svg>
```

clock.js:

```
var svgRoot = document.documentElement;
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var ident = svgRoot.createSVGMatrix();

function Pendulum(thetaZero,period,tempo,fillColor){

        //sensible default values
        thetaZero = thetaZero || 0;
        period = period || 20;
        tempo = tempo || 20;
        fillColor = fillColor || "red";

        if(fillColor == "randomize"){
                fillColor = "rgb(" + Math.random() * 254 +
                                "," + Math.random() * 254 +
                                "," + Math.random() * 254 + ")";
        }

        //construct his representation in DOM
        var g = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"g");
        g.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","translate(50,20) rotate(" + thetaZero + ")");

        var rotateTransform = g.transform.baseVal.getItem(1);

        var path = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"line");
        path.setAttributeNS(null,"x1",0);
        path.setAttributeNS(null,"y1",0);
        path.setAttributeNS(null,"x2",0);
        path.setAttributeNS(null,"y2",40);
        path.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","black");

        var c = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");
        var styleString = "fill:" +fillColor;
        //console.log(styleString);
        c.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",0);
        c.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",50);
        c.setAttributeNS(null,"r",10);
        c.setAttributeNS(null,"style",styleString);
        c.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","black");
        c.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity",.5);
        g.appendChild(path);
        g.appendChild(c);

        svgRoot.appendChild(g);

        this.node=g;

        //timeout

        var timeStep = 10; //in milliseconds
        var timeCount = 0;
        var _animateTimeStep = function(){
                timeCount++;

                var adjustedTimeCount = timeCount/tempo;

                //compute theta
                //theta(t) = period * sin(t + thetaZero)
                var theta = period * Math.sin(adjustedTimeCount  + thetaZero);

                //set his current rotate transformation to the new theta
                rotateTransform.setMatrix(ident.rotate(theta));
        }

        var timerId = null;

        //method definitions
        this.go=function(){
                timerId = window.setInterval(_animateTimeStep,timeStep);
        };

        this.stop=function(){
                window.clearInterval(timerId);
        };
}


//Pendulum(thetaZero,period,tempo,fillColor)
var p1 = new Pendulum(-10,20,40,"red");
p1.go();

var p2 = new Pendulum(20,20,40,"yellow");
p2.go();

var p3 = new Pendulum(-20,20,40,"blue");
p3.go();

var p4 = new Pendulum(10,20,40,"purple");
p4.go();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great, can i have something created in a SVG editor like inkscape and then run an animation on that object? similar to this animation.

Comment: yes, of course. this script just uses DOM to draw some simple shapes and then animates them using a sin function, which is a pretty efficient way to get an animation that looks like a pendulum. you could use any bitmap or vector image you like, though, and the technique would be the same. You would just use getElementById to get the relevant nodes out of the DOM, rather than creating them using DOM as I'm doing here.

Comment: i am trying to get this to work but somehow it doesn't animate right. see http://dev.thepenline.com/TEMP/OurClock.svg JS http://dev.thepenline.com/TEMP/OurClock.js

Answer (score 1):

With Raphael.js, you could just do:

```
var img = paper.image("image.png", 10, 10, 80, 80);
(function swingRight(){
  img.animate({'rotation': 30}, 1000, '<>', function swingLeft(){
    img.animate({'rotation': -30}, 1000, '<>', swingRight);
  });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks, How could i have it as a pendulum (with the anchor on top?)

Comment: You could just double length of the picture, so the center that's being "swung" around is at the top of the anchor.

Comment: I am not sure 100% what you mean, Please explain.

Comment: Create a new picture with twice the height of the old picture, and put the old picture in the bottom half of the new picture. Then the center of the top of the old picture will be in the center of the new picture, which will be "swung" (rotated) around with that really simple Raphael.js script.

Answer (score 1):

Using canvas

```
window.onload    = function() {
  var canvas   = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx      = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var width    = canvas.width = 500;
  var height   = canvas.height  = 300;
  var fixedx   = width/2;
  var fixedy   = 20;
  var radius   = 150;
  var dir      = 2;
  var minangle = 45;
  var maxangle = 135;
  var color = rgb();  
  var x = minangle;
  (draw = function() {
    var posx = fixedx + radius * Math.cos(x * Math.PI / 180);
    var posy = fixedy + radius * Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 180);

    with(ctx) {
      fillStyle   = '#000';
      fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      fill();
      beginPath();
      strokeStyle = '#fff';
      moveTo(fixedx, fixedy);
      lineWidth   = 5;
      lineCap     = 'round';
      lineTo(posx, posy);  
      stroke();
      closePath();
      beginPath();  
      fillStyle   = color;
      arc(posx, posy, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0);
      fill();
      closePath();
    }  
    x += 1 * dir;
    if(x >= maxangle || x <= minangle) {
      dir = -dir;
      if(Math.abs(dir) == dir) {
        color = rgb();
      }  
    }
    setTimeout(draw, 1000/30);    
  })();

  function rgb() {
    var clr = 'rgb(';
    for(var i =0; i< 3; i++) {
      clr  += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',';
    }
    return clr.replace(/\,$/,')');
  }
};
```

### [Simple Demo](http://jsbin.com/eguva4)

Comment: Dude, Thanks, but how would i have a raster image? and have it swing as a pendulum?

Answer (score 1):

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mortalis/pen/ppRNRy)

HTML:

```
<svg id="clock" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="500" height="500"> 
  <circle id="face" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"/>  
  <g id="pendulum">
    <line id="stick" x1="50" y1="50" x2="50" y2="80"/>
    <circle id="end" cx="50" cy="85" r="5"/>  
  </g>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
var amplitude=90,startAngle=90,wtime=700,timeout=40
var animation,start,correction,running=false

var pendulum = document.getElementById("pendulum")
pendulum.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + startAngle + ",50,50)")

correction=2*Math.asin(startAngle/amplitude)
start=(new Date()).getTime()
movePendulum()

function movePendulum(){
    var angle
    var pi=Math.PI,sin=Math.sin,asin=Math.asin,abs=Math.abs

    var now=(new Date()).getTime()
    var time=now-start
    time=time/wtime
    time=(time-correction)/2

    var easeVal=sin(time)
    angle=-amplitude*easeVal

    var pendulum = document.getElementById("pendulum")
    pendulum.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ",50,50)")
    animation=setTimeout(movePendulum,timeout)
}
```